# Is it possible to use mat-paginator with bootstrap tables?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I want to add paginator to bootstrap table in angular. How can I do that?

I have tried implementing the mat-paginator using the bootstrap table. The table is working fine but mat-paginator is not working. Kindly help with the .ts code for the html.
I have imported the MatSort module from @angular/material

This is the html code

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No.</th>
      <th>Branch Name</th>
      <th>Details</th>
      <th>Update</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let branch of branches; let i = index">
      <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ branch.companyBranchName }}</td>
      <td>
        <a
          routerLink="/company/branchDetails"
          [queryParams]="{
            companyBranchId: branch.id
          }"
        >
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            x="0px"
            y="0px"
            width="30"
            height="30"
            viewBox="0 0 48 48"
          >
            <path
              fill="#2196f3"
              d="M44,24c0,11.045-8.955,20-20,20S4,35.045,4,24S12.955,4,24,4S44,12.955,44,24z"
            ></path>
            <path
              fill="#fff"
              d="M22 22h4v11h-4V22zM26.5 16.5c0 1.379-1.121 2.5-2.5 2.5s-2.5-1.121-2.5-2.5S22.621 14 24 14 26.5 15.121 26.5 16.5z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a
          routerLink="/company/updateBranch"
          [queryParams]="{
            companyId: details.id,
            companyBranchId: branch.id
          }"
        >
          <img
            width="27.5"
            height="27.5"
            src="https://img.icons8.com/cotton/64/create-new--v6.png"
            alt="create-new--v6"
          />
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <svg
          (click)="deleteBranch(branch.id)"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          x="0px"
          y="0px"
          width="30"
          height="30"
          viewBox="0 0 100 100"
        >
          <path
            d="M 46 13 C 44.35503 13 43 14.35503 43 16 L 43 18 L 32.265625 18 C 30.510922 18 28.879517 18.922811 27.976562 20.427734 L 26.433594 23 L 23 23 C 20.802666 23 19 24.802666 19 27 C 19 29.197334 20.802666 31 23 31 L 24.074219 31 L 27.648438 77.458984 C 27.88773 80.575775 30.504529 83 33.630859 83 L 66.369141 83 C 69.495471 83 72.11227 80.575775 72.351562 77.458984 L 75.925781 31 L 77 31 C 79.197334 31 81 29.197334 81 27 C 81 24.802666 79.197334 23 77 23 L 73.566406 23 L 72.023438 20.427734 C 71.120481 18.922811 69.489078 18 67.734375 18 L 57 18 L 57 16 C 57 14.35503 55.64497 13 54 13 L 46 13 z M 46 15 L 54 15 C 54.56503 15 55 15.43497 55 16 L 55 18 L 45 18 L 45 16 C 45 15.43497 45.43497 15 46 15 z M 32.265625 20 L 43.832031 20 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 44.158203 20 L 55.832031 20 A 1.0001 1.0001 0 0 0 56.158203 20 L 67.734375 20 C 68.789672 20 69.763595 20.551955 70.306641 21.457031 L 71.833984 24 L 68.5 24 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 1 0 68.5 25 L 73.5 25 L 77 25 C 78.116666 25 79 25.883334 79 27 C 79 28.116666 78.116666 29 77 29 L 23 29 C 21.883334 29 21 28.116666 21 27 C 21 25.883334 21.883334 25 23 25 L 27 25 L 61.5 25 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 1 0 61.5 24 L 28.166016 24 L 29.693359 21.457031 C 30.236405 20.551955 31.210328 20 32.265625 20 z M 64.5 24 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 1 0 64.5 25 L 66.5 25 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 1 0 66.5 24 L 64.5 24 z M 26.078125 31 L 73.921875 31 L 70.357422 77.306641 C 70.196715 79.39985 68.46881 81 66.369141 81 L 33.630859 81 C 31.53119 81 29.803285 79.39985 29.642578 77.306641 L 26.078125 31 z M 38 35 C 36.348906 35 35 36.348906 35 38 L 35 73 C 35 74.651094 36.348906 76 38 76 C 39.651094 76 41 74.651094 41 73 L 41 38 C 41 36.348906 39.651094 35 38 35 z M 50 35 C 48.348906 35 47 36.348906 47 38 L 47 73 C 47 74.651094 48.348906 76 50 76 C 51.651094 76 53 74.651094 53 73 L 53 69.5 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 1 0 52 69.5 L 52 73 C 52 74.110906 51.110906 75 50 75 C 48.889094 75 48 74.110906 48 73 L 48 38 C 48 36.889094 48.889094 36 50 36 C 51.110906 36 52 36.889094 52 38 L 52 63.5 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 1 0 53 63.5 L 53 38 C 53 36.348906 51.651094 35 50 35 z M 62 35 C 60.348906 35 59 36.348906 59 38 L 59 39.5 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 1 0 60 39.5 L 60 38 C 60 36.889094 60.889094 36 62 36 C 63.110906 36 64 36.889094 64 38 L 64 73 C 64 74.110906 63.110906 75 62 75 C 60.889094 75 60 74.110906 60 73 L 60 47.5 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 1 0 59 47.5 L 59 73 C 59 74.651094 60.348906 76 62 76 C 63.651094 76 65 74.651094 65 73 L 65 38 C 65 36.348906 63.651094 35 62 35 z M 38 36 C 39.110906 36 40 36.889094 40 38 L 40 73 C 40 74.110906 39.110906 75 38 75 C 36.889094 75 36 74.110906 36 73 L 36 38 C 36 36.889094 36.889094 36 38 36 z M 59.492188 41.992188 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 0 0 59 42.5 L 59 44.5 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 1 0 60 44.5 L 60 42.5 A 0.50005 0.50005 0 0 0 59.492188 41.992188 z"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<mat-paginator
  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15, 20]"
  showFirstLastButtons
></mat-paginator>
```